# quotes in the java regular expressions

Tags: java, regex

I get a String from the JSP, containing [", e.g.

```
["Bulgaria
```

I would like to replace all the [" occurrences for [', but I don't know exactly how to do it...

I just tried:

```
str = str.replaceAll("[\\\"", "['");
```

with the result

```
java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed character class near index 2 [\"
```

and

`html = html.replaceAll("[\"", "['");`

with the result

```
java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed character class near index 1 [" ^
```

any help will be appreciated

Comment: `[` is a special character that needs to be escaped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
str.replaceAll("\\[\"", "['");
```

You need `\\` to escape in java regex and `[` is a special character in java regex, thus the `\\` in front of it. `"` is a special character in strings so you only need one `\` to escape it.

Answer (score 0):

```
"Test[\"".replaceAll("\\[\"", "['"); // Test['
```